# String concatenation with XQL

Tags: xml

I have XQL service and I want to perform a XQL query, where the result should be the concatenation of two fields.
Is there a concatenation function in the XQL language at all?
I found in the XQL [documentation](http://ibiblio.org/xql/xql-design.html), that `$union$` returns list of results, but I need a single string as result.

For example, if the input is

```
<test>
    <a>A</a>
    <b>B</b>
</test>
```

I need a single XQL query, which to return "AB".

Is it possible to do that with XQL ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by XQL? The only XQL that I'm aware of is a 1998 proposal for an XML query language that eventually became XQuery.

Comment: http://www.ibiblio.org/xql/xql-design.html

Comment: That's an ancient spec and I wasn't aware there were any active implementations. I'd suggest you move forward to XQuery.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I am let's say.. limited by the technologies of my project :D So while we are using Software AG's Trading Networks, we have to deal with XQL :)

Comment: You've probably noticed there is no StackOverflow tag for "XQL". I'm afraid that probably means there's no-one here who can help you.

Comment: Hope dies last :)